# Playing an mp3 file from the assets folder with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, audio, howler.js

Trying to play an mp3 file with howler.js from the assets folder in the latest version of Angular.

I put an MP3 in `src/assets/mp3/lost-in-sands-126335.mp3`.

```
 audio % ls src/assets/mp3/lost-in-sands-126335.mp3 
src/assets/mp3/lost-in-sands-126335.mp3
```

This is what I have within the constructor of `app.component`:

```
  mp3URL:string = 'assets/mp3/lost-in-sands-126335.mp3';
  constructor() {
     const song = new Howl({
      //  autoplay: true,
      loop: true,
      volume: 1,
      format: ['mp3'],
      src: [this.mp3URL],
    });    
   song.play();
   console.log(`IS THE SONG PLAYING: `, song.playing());
```

When the application is served `ng serve -o` the song does not start playing (The console log of `song.playing()` is false.

Any ideas?